# Default Template, From address and Subject lines for email

Tags: email, email-template

I have an request from our users for which I need help.

Our users need a particular email template to be the default template, along with From address to default to **support@xxx.com** instead of their names. The subject line should have the Case Number and the text from the subject filed in every email being sent out from Salesforce. This is because they send out  many emails in one day and to have to chose a template every time they send it out, it’s a time taking process and has chance for human error.

Is there anyway we could automate the process?

Comment: How are these emails being sent? Is there a workflow or something?

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to set support@xxx.com as a Organization-Wide Email Address if not already done. 
Next, find the ID of the template that you want to use. 
Third, create a new Detail Page Button on the case that executes the following Javascript (replacing the template ID where you see **00XCXXXXXXXXXXX** and put the correct return address in where the **support@xxx.com** is:

```
location.replace('/email/author/emailauthor.jsp?retURL=/{!Case.Id}&p3_lkid={!Case.Id}&rtype=003&p2_lkid={!Case.ContactId}&template_id=00XCXXXXXXXXXXX&p26=support@xxx.com');
```

Finally, place the new button on the case page. The template should include all of your required fields (case number in the subject, etc) and then pressing the button from the case should do exactly what you are looking for.